# How to start Google service

Tags: java, android

I tried to "Get started Android" in Google cloud messaging, and got this:

> Get the project
>
> If this is your first time using a Google services sample, check out the google-services repository.
>
> $ git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git
>
> Open Android Studio.
>
> Select File > Open, browse to where you cloned the google-services repository, and open google-services/android/gcm (if you are in the Android Studio start screen, you can select Import Non-Android Studio project and use this same path).

I am using Mac OS X. Where can I put this command:
$ git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git ?

Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go to *VCS* > *Checkout from Version Control*.
Next, choose *Github*.

Enter your Master Password (Password configured for the Git Acess in AS).
Then a window is visible with a field *Github Repository URL*.

Key up the URL : https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git